# Cant seam to get PHP login to work, used to work but slightly changed it

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication, pdo

I made a login that worked perfectly, but now im copying the original and editing it to work on another one of my web projects and it jsut dosnt seam to want to work, any help would be appreciated!

Here is the login that worked:

```
<?php

session_start();

include('../includes/connect-db.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Message would go here</div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if (empty($username) or empty($password)) {
            $error = 'All fields are required!';
        } else {
            $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username = ? AND user_password = ?');

            $query->bindValue(1, $username);
            $query->bindValue(2, $password);

            $query->execute();

            $num = $query->rowCount();

            if ($num == 1) {
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                header('Location: index.php');
                exit();
            } else {
                $error = 'Incorrect details!';
            }
        }
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Login form would go here</div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php } ?>
```

And here is the login im trying to get to work (some more info about it under the code):

```
<?php
//Start Session
session_start();

//Connect To DataBase
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'includes/connect-db.php');

//Login
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    header('Location: http://localhost/logged-in.html');
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if (empty($username) or empty($password)) {
            $error = 'All fields are required!';
        } else {
            $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM admins WHERE admin_username = ? AND admin_password = ?');

            $query->bindValue(1, $username);
            $query->bindValue(2, $password);

            $query->execute();

            $num = $query->rowCount();

            if ($num == 1) {
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                header('Location: http://localhost/techbite/logged-in.html');
                exit();
            } else {
                $error = 'Incorrect details!';
            }
        }
    }

//Page Content
$content = '<form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
    <small style="color:#aa0000"><?php echo($error); ?></small>
<?php } ?>';

//Select Theme
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'themes/theme-select.php');

}
?>
```

Keep in mind that database connection is successful, the login form appears but just dosnt seam to log in or show an error when nothing is entered/wrong credentials, everything else works perfect, including importing the form into the theme with $content.

Here is the connect-db.php:

```
<?php
//Connect To Database
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=techbite', 'root', '');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit('Database error, could not connect.');
}
?>
```

What iv done here is included the theme:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/themes/theme-select.php');
```

And inside the theme where i want the content i have:

```
<?php echo($content); ?>
```

and in the login php file i have this which will be put into the php theme file:

```
$content = '<form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
    <small style="color:#aa0000"><?php echo($error); ?></small>
<?php } ?>';
```

I hope someone can help, hopefully its something small i have missed!

Thanks for any help and let me know if anything else is needed.

Kind Regards,
Hayden.

Comment: just a remark: are you really storing the admin-password in plain text in the database? This is not a good practice ! Just Google on "Why not to store passwords in plain text", and you'll find a lot of reasons. On https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm you can find how you should do it :-)

Comment: Hi DaveG, yes i know about passwords in database, since this is local and on a WAMP server i was just using it to get it working, when its on my hosting server i will be making it secure, but thank you for the heads up! :)

Comment: This is programming not quilting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!
i knew it would be something so small and simple, it was the form action which was set to the wrong file name, it was set to index.php instead of login.php.

Thank you to everyone for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

it's not showing an error because

```
$content = '<form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </form>
<?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
    <small style="color:#aa0000"><?php echo($error); ?></small>
<?php } ?>';
```

is all just a string, and the `<?php ?>` sections inside this string are never parsed by the php interpreter. View the page source of your login page and you should see them there.

If you're set on using this $content variable and the theme-select.php file, try changing it to this:

```
$content = '<form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </form>';
if (isset($error)) {
    $content .= '<small style="color:#aa0000">'.$error.'</small>';
}
```

As for why it's not logging in, it's a silly question, but have you created a table in your database named admins and a record there with a username and password set?

Comment: Hi Luke, thats understandable, however when i tested it as a html form and not a string i had the same results, no error, no login.

Comment: Do you see the `<?php` tags after your form when you view-source on the login page? I can't give you any answers about when you had it as an html form as you haven't provided that information.

Comment: With the php inside the $content =''; i do see the php tags, but with the standard html form there were no php tags

Comment: As I said, I can't offer advice about the standard html form as you haven't put that code up. If you see the php tags in the html source they're not being interpreted and this is why you **currently** see no login error. Did you try the fix? The no-login part is a separate error, have you checked the admins table exists?

Comment: The form is exactly the same as whats inside `$content = '';`
so it would be  `<form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> </form>
<?php if (isset($error)) { ?>
    <small style="color:#aa0000"><?php echo($error); ?></small>
<?php } ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
$num = $query->rowCount();
```

with

```
$num = count($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

**UPDATE**

Just noticed this...

```
if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
```

should be

```
if( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) ) {
```

I would add an else condition here to display an error message of some description

**UPDATE 2**

Slight modification to your connect.php

```
try {
    // create a new instance of a PDO connection
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=techbite', 'root', '');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    // if the connection fails, display an error message
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Hi Adrock, thanks for your answer, i tried replacing it but it still seams to be doing the same thing though, any ideas?

Comment: Apart from my update, if you run just the code to query the database, does that work

Comment: Hmm, no it dosnt seam to work or give any data! I have just tried copying the entire code from the login i have that works, into this web project (and changed directory names and database table names to work with this one) and that dosnt seam to work either, im sure its connecting fine, but just in-case here is the database connection:

<?php
//Connect To Database
try {
 $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=techbite', 'root', '');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
 exit('Database error, could not connect.');
}
?>

Comment: Iv added it to the main question :)

Comment: I've added a part to your database connection to catch an error

Comment: rowCount is fine, and use PDO::errorInfo to get the correct error.

Comment: No there wasn't any errors, the login form is still acting the same,i wonder why it works so well on the other, but when copied to this web project it dosnt do anything, even though everything seams correct.